# How to change account in OneNote 2016

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote-2016

When I launch OneNote 2016 (the desktop app for windows 10) it tries to automatically log me into my work account.
But since that isn't associated with a OneNote account, it fails to log me in and displays a dialog saying something like *"Could not connect. You can move your your notebooks to the cloud later"* and a Close-button.

How do I change my OneNote account? Since I'm never able to actually start the OneNote software, I can't do it from there.

I've checked under  Control Panel > Credentials Manager but from what I can tell there's nothing oneNote related in there. I removed my Skydrive account to be sure it wasn't trying to use that one, but it had no effect.

I would be open to uninstalling OneNote if that's the only way. But it seems to be part of the Office package and lacks a separate uninstallation...

Answer (score 0):

there are other threads related to this issue... OneNote is a part of Office so, a reinstall and update of Office is what's needed if you go down that route. Otherwise, there is an itemization in credentials manager for Office:

1. Open Credential Manager (go to the Start screen and start typing "credential", it should be among the first results).
2. Click "Windows Credentials".
3. Under "Generic Credentials", find the entry that starts with "MicrosoftOffice15_Data".
4. Expand that entry and click on "Remove".
5. Now open any Office program. Check the top right corner, it should require you to log in. Do so, and your documents and OneNote notebooks should sync again.

[Change OneNote Account info](https://superuser.com/questions/662952/cant-sign-in-to-office-and-onenote-cant-connect-to-skydrive-in-windows-8-1)

Lemme know if that solves it?